# Make a column of two plots

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a pair of functions of the same variable one above the other. A simple example is

```
Column[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}],
  Plot[-Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]
}]
```

Here's the result. The abscissae axes are shifted due to labels being of different sizes. How do I put one exactly under the other?

[image]

Comment: Several ways to do this, e.g. add `ImagePadding -> {{20, All}, {All, All}}` to each plot...

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can line them up with `ImagePadding`.

```
Column[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1},
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {10, 10}}],
  Plot[-Sin[x], {x, 0, 1},
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {10, 10}}]}]
```